# Fragment is added,has data but UI is blank when rotated

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

I have an activity which should display two `Fragments` in portrait mode and one `Fragment` in landscape mode. Everything is good in normal state.But when i rotate from landscape to portrait blank UI is only displayed.Both the fragments have data, attached to the activity but the UI is blank when displayed. Checked many SO answers but none solved my problem.

*StepDetailActivity.java :*

```
package com.example.codelabs.baking.ui.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.codelabs.baking.R;
import com.example.codelabs.baking.model.Recipe;
import com.example.codelabs.baking.model.Step;
import com.example.codelabs.baking.ui.fragment.StepDetailFragment;
import com.example.codelabs.baking.ui.fragment.VideoPlayerFragment;
import com.example.codelabs.baking.utils.RecipeUtils;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;

public class StepDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements StepDetailFragment.TextClicked {
    public static final String EXTRA_STEP_POSITION = "stepclickedPosition";
    public static final String EXTRA_RECIPE_ID = "clickedrecipeid";
    public static final String KEY_STEP_POSITION = "keystepclickedPosition";
    public static final String KEY_RECIPE_ID = "keyclickedrecipeid";
    public static final String KEY_VIDEO_PLAYER_FRAGMENT = "keyvideoplayerfragment";
    public static final String KEY_STEP_DETAIL_FRAGMENT = "keystepdetailfragment";
    FrameLayout fm;
    SimpleExoPlayerView playerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    ImageButton mPreviousButton;
    ImageButton mNextButton;
    int currentId, previousId, nextId = 0;
    VideoPlayerFragment videoPlayerfragment;
    StepDetailFragment stepDetailFragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private Step mStepObject, mStepObjectBackup;
    private Recipe mClickedRecipe, mClickedRecipeBackup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_step_detail);
        Intent stepIntent = getIntent();
        mStepObject = mStepObjectBackup = stepIntent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_STEP_POSITION);
        mClickedRecipe = mClickedRecipeBackup = stepIntent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_RECIPE_ID);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mClickedRecipe.getmRecipeName());
        if (this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet) && RecipeUtils.isLandscape(this)) {
            finish();
        }
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            videoPlayerfragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
            videoPlayerfragment.setmStepObject(mStepObject);
            videoPlayerfragment.setMediaUrl(mStepObject.getmVideoUrl());
            stepDetailFragment = new StepDetailFragment();
            stepDetailFragment.setStepObject(mStepObject);
            stepDetailFragment.setStepClickedRecipeObject(mClickedRecipe);
            if (!(RecipeUtils.isLandscape(StepDetailActivity.this))) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_media_playerView, videoPlayerfragment, "video_player_fragment");
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_description, stepDetailFragment, "step_detail_fragment");

            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_media_playerView, videoPlayerfragment, "video_player_fragment");
            }


        } else {

            mStepObject = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(EXTRA_STEP_POSITION);
            mClickedRecipe = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(EXTRA_RECIPE_ID);
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("video_player_fragment") != null) {
                videoPlayerfragment = (VideoPlayerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, KEY_VIDEO_PLAYER_FRAGMENT);
            } else {
                videoPlayerfragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
                videoPlayerfragment.setmStepObject(mStepObject);
                videoPlayerfragment.setMediaUrl(mStepObject.getmVideoUrl());
            }

            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("step_detail_fragment") != null) {
                stepDetailFragment = (StepDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, KEY_STEP_DETAIL_FRAGMENT);

            } else {
                stepDetailFragment = new StepDetailFragment();
                stepDetailFragment.setStepClickedRecipeObject(mClickedRecipe);
                stepDetailFragment.setStepObject(mStepObject);


            }
            if (!(RecipeUtils.isLandscape(StepDetailActivity.this))) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_media_playerView, videoPlayerfragment);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_description, stepDetailFragment);
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(
                        R.id.frame_media_playerView, videoPlayerfragment);
            }
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (videoPlayerfragment.isAdded())
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, KEY_VIDEO_PLAYER_FRAGMENT, videoPlayerfragment);
        if (stepDetailFragment.isAdded())
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, KEY_STEP_DETAIL_FRAGMENT, stepDetailFragment);
        outState.putParcelable(KEY_STEP_POSITION, mStepObject);
        outState.putParcelable(KEY_RECIPE_ID, mClickedRecipe);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_STEP_POSITION) != null) {
            mStepObject = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_STEP_POSITION);
        } else {
            mStepObject = mStepObjectBackup;
        }
        if (savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_RECIPE_ID) != null) {
            mClickedRecipe = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_RECIPE_ID);
        } else {
            mClickedRecipe = mClickedRecipeBackup;
        }
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("video_player_fragment") != null) {
            videoPlayerfragment = (VideoPlayerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, KEY_VIDEO_PLAYER_FRAGMENT);
//            videoPlayerfragment.setmStepObject(mStepObject);
//            videoPlayerfragment.setMediaUrl(mStepObject.getmVideoUrl());
        } else {
            videoPlayerfragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
            videoPlayerfragment.setmStepObject(mStepObject);
            videoPlayerfragment.setMediaUrl(mStepObject.getmVideoUrl());
        }

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("step_detail_fragment") != null) {
            stepDetailFragment = (StepDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, KEY_STEP_DETAIL_FRAGMENT);
//            stepDetailFragment.setStepClickedRecipeObject(mClickedRecipe);
//            stepDetailFragment.setStepObject(mStepObject);

        } else {
            stepDetailFragment = new StepDetailFragment();
            stepDetailFragment.setStepClickedRecipeObject(mClickedRecipe);
            stepDetailFragment.setStepObject(mStepObject);

        }
        if (!(RecipeUtils.isLandscape(StepDetailActivity.this))) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "ls elsuu stepid" + mStepObject.getmId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_media_playerView, videoPlayerfragment);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_description, stepDetailFragment);
            if (videoPlayerfragment.isAdded()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "vp fragment irukku", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "vp fragment illa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //clearBackStack();
            if (videoPlayerfragment.isAdded()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "sd fragment irukku", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "sd fragment illa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            mStepObject = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_STEP_POSITION);
            mClickedRecipe = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_RECIPE_ID);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_media_playerView, videoPlayerfragment);
            //fragmentTransaction.show(stepDetailFragment);

            //clearBackStack();
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void sendVideoUrl(Step mStepooo) {
        videoPlayerfragment.trigger(mStepooo.getmVideoUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public void sendDescription(Step mStepObject) {
        stepDetailFragment.setDescription(mStepObject.getmDescription());

    }

}
```

Github link :

https://github.com/varshaaraman/baking/tree/aftersubmission

Comment: test case try this **`android:configChanges="orientation"`** in your manifest file

Comment: @NileshRathod he should not doing this ... *Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort*